# Running Certbot to add new domains to an existing installation

Tags: nginx, ssl, tls

I just finished running Certbot instructions located at:

[Ubuntu Certbot Instructions](https://certbot.eff.org/instructions?ws=nginx&os=ubuntufocal)

Certbot automatically detected my domain and installed the certificate, everything worked perfectly.

What I need to know is when I add new websites, will I be able to repeat the installation without affecting existing website(s)?  E.g.:

```
$ sudo certbot --nginx
```

Unfortunately, this is **not specified in the FAQ**.  I've looked online but have only found old messages that use older instructions and versions of Certbot which are not compatible.

My main concern is that new certificates will be issued which may possible lead to temporary quirks experienced by users.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a new domain at a later time, you can run:

```
$ sudo certbot --nginx
```

Certbot will use your nginx configuration file(s) to search for all the possible hostnames and ask you for which hostname you want a certificate. There you could either just **select the new hostname(s)** for a new certificate **or select all the hostnames** so Certbot will extend the already existing certificate.